# SERVER-SIDE mp3 pitch/key change

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, signalr, mp3

I am making a karaoke site for virtual karaoke. I already have every feature you can think of but one. There is no Key Change functionality. I am using Html/Javascript/Jquery on the front end and asp.net on the back end. Does anyone know of any way to do the pitch changes on the server-side?

for those who don't know, karaoke songs consist of 2 files that are zipped. You have a CDG file for the graphics and an MP3 file for the audio. To save space, I do keep the songs zipped. The CDG part of the duo (which is normally around the same size as the mp3) zips down to almost 10% of the original size so it only makes sense to store them this way.

Right now, when a user selects a song to sing, the server unzips the files into a temporary folder. They hang out in this folder until the Dj marks the song as sang. at that time it deletes the files from the temp folder.

With that being said, I think it would be best to have an **ASP.Net server-side solution** since the signalR hub can process the pitch change while the site goes on without notice.

I have also read about pitch changing by stretching or compressing the length of the audio file. This will not work in this case and will make the lyrics not match the song.

Thanks ahead of time!!!

-Guy Cothal (kara.guycothal.com)

P.S. I am looking for a purely server-side solution at this point. Must be in VB or C#.

Comment: If you're only looking for a server-side solution now, why does your question say client-side or server-side?  Also, you could have just edited your previous question instead of re-creating it.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out!!! I ended up using the NAudio library found in NuGet. Here is the code behind it.

```
Public Shared Function pitchChange(sFileIn As String, sFileOut As String, iPitch As Integer) As Boolean
    Dim semitone = Math.Pow(2, (iPitch / 1) / 12)
    Try
        Using reader = New MediaFoundationReader(sFileIn)
            Dim pitch = New SmbPitchShiftingSampleProvider(reader.ToSampleProvider())
            Using device = New WaveOutEvent()
                pitch.PitchFactor = CSng(semitone)
                MediaFoundationEncoder.EncodeToMp3(pitch.ToWaveProvider(), sFileOut, 48000)
            End Using
        End Using
        Return True
    Catch exception As Exception
        Throw exception
        Return False
    End Try
End Function
```

I tested 12 steps either direction. takes about 20-25 secs to convert, but this is done way before it is needed.